# How to display CheckBoxes in DropDownList in ASP.Net for Multiple Selections

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to fetch data in the DropDownList from database.So how can i display multiple CheckBoxe in DropDownList.Please help.

Comment: There is control called checkboxlist use that. Try looking at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Also this one http://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you are using jquery here is a [link](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/)

Answer (score 0):

try this one :)

The DevExpress ASP.NET List Box (ASPxListBox) editor allows multiple list items to be selected at the same time. Selection behavior is controlled by the editor's SelectionMode property. Depending on this property's setting, the following selection modes are available within the ASPxListBox editor:

Single - Only one item can be selected within the editor.
Multiple - Multiple items can be selected within the editor. End-users can apply multi-selection by clicking list items while pressing Ctrl (to add an individual item) or Shift (to select a range of items).
CheckColumn - Multiple items can be selected within the editor. End-users can apply multi-selection by clicking list items (the Shift key can also be used in this mode to select a range of items).
When multiple selection is enabled, the selection state of individual items can be specified via the Selected property of the item, and a collection of selected items can be obtained by using the SelectedItems or SelectedIndices property. In addition, item selection can be applied on the client side by using a specific client API (the editor's GetSelectedItems, SelectItems, UnselectItems client methods).

Note that in multiple selection mode, all ASPxListBox's features are supported, with the exception of loading items on demand via callbacks (which is usually controlled by the editor's EnableCallbackMode and CallBackPageSize properties).

[List Box with Multiple Selection](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ListEditors/MultiSelect.aspx)